# How to put correctly glyph icon right align and text align centered

Tags: dreamweaver

I am working on a project in bootstrap and my problem is I wanted to align the text in navigation bar to center and glyphicons to right and I tried like navbar-right and text align center but it's not working for me correctly please help me on this.

toggle navigation
            
            
            
        
        logo here

```
    <h4 class="navbar-text">SOME TEXT HERE</h4>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share your full code like HTML+CSS

Answer (score 0):

In li tag after glyphicons add padding css to 50% than text will come at center